# Recursive General Tree Method ClassCastException

Tags: java, recursion

I'm working on a recursive method in my FileSystem program. The FileSystem takes the shape of a General Tree. I have two types of files in the general tree: `Directory` and `TextFile`.

Here is my `findFile` recursive method:

```
//Find any file by name
private File findFile(File f, String name){
    if(f.getName().equals(name))
        return f;
    File file = null;
    for(File c : ((Directory) f).getChildren()){
        file = findFile(c, name);
        if(file != null)
            break;
    }
    return file;
}
```

I have a `File` class that `Directory` and `TextFile` inherit. My `getChildren()` method is only in `Directory` and returns an `ArrayList<File>` type.

The problem I'm running into is once I make a couple directories and text files. If I change my `currentDirectory` to something deeper in the tree `findFile` will throw a `ClassCastException`.

I've figured out why it does this, and I'll illustrate it here:

```
       D1
     /   \
    D2     D4
   / \     \
 TF1   D3     D5
```

In this illustrations `D` stands for a `Directory`, and `TF` stands for a `TextFile`.

Right after `TF1` is created, let's say I want to change my working directory to `D4`. This will throw the `ClassCastException` because `findFile` is a preorder traversal.

Is there anyway I can adjust this method to recognize a `TextFile` when it's next in line, and skip over it to avoid my programming trying to get the `TextFile`'s children?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
private File findFile(File f, String name){
    if(f.getName().equals(name))
        return f;
    File file = null;
    if (f.isDirectory()) {
        for(File c : ((Directory) f).getChildren()){
            file = findFile(c, name);
            if(file != null)
                break; 
        }
    }
    return file;
}
```